call getReserves() function using yul in solidity
what wrong with getReserves2 in A contract, why I cannot staticcall to Pair contract?
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

contract Pair {
    function getReserves() external pure returns (uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1, uint32 blockTimestampLast) {
        return (1, 2, 3);
    }
}

contract A {
    Pair pair;
    constructor() {
        pair = new Pair();
    }

    function getPairAddr() external  view returns (address) {
        return address(pair);
    }

    function getReserves() external  view returns (uint256 reserve0, uint256 reserve1) {
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = address(pair).staticcall(abi.encodeWithSelector(0x0902f1ac));
        require(success, 'UniV2Pair: failed to fetch reserves');
        assembly {
            reserve0 := mload(add(data, 0x20))
            reserve1 := mload(add(data, 0x40))
        }
    }

    function getReserves2() external  view returns (uint256 reserve0, uint256 reserve1) {
        address poolAddr = address(pair);
        assembly ("memory-safe") {  // solhint-disable-line no-inline-assembly
            function reRevert() {
                returndatacopy(0, 0, returndatasize())
                revert(0, returndatasize())
            }
            let emptyPtr := mload(0x40)
            mstore(emptyPtr, 0x0902f1ac) // getReserves selector
            if iszero(staticcall(gas(), poolAddr, emptyPtr, 0x4, emptyPtr, 0x40)) {
                reRevert()
            }
            reserve0 := mload(emptyPtr)
            reserve1 := mload(add(emptyPtr, 0x20))
        }
    }
}


mstore(emptyPtr, 0x0902f1ac) will write in the memory slot the following 32 bytes: 0x000..00000902f1ac. So the selector will be written at the end. You don't want that since you'll be using the 4 leftmost bytes as calldata.
Shifting the bytes to the left will make it work:
mstore(emptyPtr, shl(224, 0x0902f1ac))  // 224 = 256-4*8

